# How to reference a page with parameters Wicket

Tags: java, parameters, wicket, hyperlink

I need to send Wicket links (through mail, for example) which references instances in the system.

For example, the mail could contain:

From: ...@...
To: ...@...
Subject: Order Pending

... txt...
Click here to go: http://I.dont.care.the.style.of.the.linkPage.OrderDetailPage?orderId=1001
... txt...

I have two constructor of this OrderDetailPage

```
public class OrderDetailPage extends BasePage {

public OrderDetailPage(PageParameters parameters){
    this(OrderRepository.getById(parameters.getAsInteger("orderId")), null);
}


public OrderDetailPage(Order order, WebPage back) {
       super(new CompoundPropertyModel<Order>(order));
       //Renders the page for the order received.
       //back is the page we came from. Null hides link.

       ...
    }
...
}
```

I don't know how to send the links, because, I can't create a Bookmarkable Link because it looks for the default constructor... and of course, I don't have one.

What I'm doing for another page is:

```
final PageParameters pars = new PageParameters();
pars.add("orderId", "1001");

BookmarkablePageLink<Void> link = new BookmarkablePageLink<Void>("alink", OrderDetailPage.class, pars); 
                        
link.add(new Label("id", "1001"));  
add(link);
```

Markup:

```
<li><a href="#" wicket:id="alink"><span wicket:id="id"/></a></li>
```

The generated URL is

```
http://localhost:8080/wicket/bookmarkable/packagePath.OrderDetailPage?orderId=1001
```

Which is OK, but Still, doesn't call the "parameters" constructor.

FIX:

I fix this, but I know the solution is NOT OK.

```
public OrderDetailPage() {
        this(WicketApplication.orderRepository.get(Integer
                .parseInt(RequestCycle.get().getRequest()
                        .getRequestParameters().getParameterValue("orderId").toString())),
                null);

    }
```

EDIT: I read something about "mounting" the URL, could this work? How?

Answer (score 13):

The `BookMarkablePageLink` has 2 constructors: one for connecting to the default constructor of the linked page, and one with an extra parameter to supply the link with `PageParameters`, which will call the constructor with the `PageParameters`.

You create the link like so:

```
PageParameters pars = new PageParameters();
pars.add("id", 12345);
add(new BookmarkablePageLink("id", MyPage.class, pars);
```

This also works with the `setResponsePage` method:

```
PageParameters pars = new PageParameters();
pars.add("id", 12345);
setResponsePage(MyPage.class, pars);
```

Comment: It's still says: WicketMessage: Unable to create page from class packagePath.OrderDetailPage. Class does not have a visible default contructor. It doesn't call the "Parameters" constructor.

Comment: Can you show some code? Because this is the way I do this too.

Comment: Then there is something wrong in your code, which is not visible in the snippets you have provided. The API hasn't changed since Wicket 1.0 AFAIK.

Comment: I do that. When I follow the link, I get OrderDetailPage has not a visible default constructor. Should I have it? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Which version of wicket are you using? Unless you are using a final release (1.5.0 or 1.4.18) you might run into a weird bug. Try reproducing in a quick start with only the bookmarkable link and pages. See also the link examples located here: http://wicket-examples.herokuapp.com/linkomatic/home

Comment: Yes, your constructor must be either public default, or public with `PageParameters`. Otherwise Wicket cannot instantiate your page.